# Is this post really spam or offensive?

Tags: discussion

I was asked to review [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/4188/preventing-brute-force-attacks-against-ssh/896210#896210). I thought it looked okay, so I accepted it and got the "You didn't pass" nag. The post had been deleted as "spam or offensive".

Does that seem right? The user was promoting a script he developed; okay. Maybe his code is crap and no one should use it; okay. But to me, none of that adds up to spam. It looks to me like a legitimate attempt to answer the question. Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Self-promotional posts often are flagged as spam by the community. A moderator accepted the spam flag. Thus the post became eligible to be a review audit.

I probably would not have accepted the spam flag. The user clearly made the necessary disclosures, and the script was a potential solution to the problem given in the question.

The [help center](https://serverfault.com/help/behavior) states:

> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; [contact our ad sales team](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact) for details. We also offer [free community promotion ads](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) for open source projects and non-profit organizations.